# Flutter : Listview filter to create another list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm sorry but I'm new to this language
I made a page with three sections
The first section is for all servers, the second section is for free servers, and the third section is for free servers
I used listview.builder with Getx and created a list of all servers
But I don't know how to show only free servers or paid servers only
The only thing I did was show all servers
And I don't want to create three separate lists for the three sections
I want one list and do a view according to each section
[image]

controller

```
var servers = List.from([
    {
      'name' : 'Singapore',
      'flag' : 'assets/images/flags/singapore.png',
      'cnumber' : 7,
      'isvip' : false
    },
    {
      'name' : 'United States',
      'flag' : 'assets/images/flags/usa.png',
      'cnumber' : 3,
      'isvip' : true
    },
    {
      'name' : 'Netherlands',
      'flag' : 'assets/images/flags/netherlands.png',
      'cnumber' : 8,
      'isvip' : false
    },
    {
      'name' : 'Argentina',
      'flag' : 'assets/images/flags/argentina.png',
      'cnumber' : '2',
      'isvip' : false
    },

  ]).obs;
```

I use a variable (isvip) to create a paid subscription icon
But I don't know how to use it to filter it to another list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're trying to make two lists, one for free servers and one for non-free servers? If so, give the following a go:

Firstly, make a new class (custom "server" object) like so:

```
class Server{
  String name;
  String flag;
  int number;
  bool isVIP;

  Item({required this.name, required this.flag, required this.number, required this.isVIP});
}
```

Next, change your servers to be a list that uses your server item:

```
var servers = [
    Server(
        name: "Singapore",
        flag: "assets/images/flags/singapore.png",
        number: 7,
        isVIP: false),
    Server(
        name: "United States",
        flag: "assets/images/flags/usa.png",
        number: 3,
        isVIP: true),
  ];
// The rest of your items, and add new items by doing:
// servers.add(Item(...));
```

Lastly, you can query the list by doing the following:

```
List<Item> vipServers = [];
setState(() {
      vipServers = (servers.where((element) => element.isVIP)).toList();
    });
// You can query the list by any of your server objects fields by changing the 
// "element.isVIP"
```

Edit: Just realised I missed part of your question. For changing the Listview, you can do the following:

Set a new `List<Server> currentServerList` and whenever you need to change which servers are being seen - for example, when a user clicks "Free Servers" simply do:

```
setState(() {currentServerList = (servers.where((element) => !element.isVIP)).toList();});
```

and have your ListView like this:

```
ListView(
          children: List.generate(currentServerList.length, (index) {
            return Text(currentServerList[index].name);
            // Whatever you wish to do inside your listview.
          }),
        ),
```

Edit Edit (see comments):

You can make a list of VIP servers by doing:

```
List<Server> vipServers = [];
setState(() {
      vipServers = (servers.where((element) => element.isVIP)).toList();
    });
// You can query the list by any of your server objects fields by changing the 
// "element.isVIP"
```

And you can make a list of free servers by doing:

```
List<Server> freeServers = [];
setState(() {
      vipServers = (servers.where((element) => !element.isVIP)).toList();
    });
// note the "!element.isVIP" meaning, where it is NOT isVIP.
```

You can merge these by doing

```
List<Server> allServers = vipServers + freeServers;
```

Comment: trying to make two lists free and vip servers , Is there another way?
I use getx and the method you said is a little complicated and I tried but I had a lot of problems I don't know maybe because I use getx

Comment: Or is it possible to make two lists (free servers / vip servers) and then merge them into a new list (all servers)?

Comment: Hey @MedoAhmed it is possible to do that! I'll edit the answer to show how! :) I hope that solves your problem? I'm not sure about much to do with GetX to be honest... if it didn't help then please describe to me the problem I'm missing and I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: Hey @Percent.twof Thank you very much my friend, I have one last problem and I hope you can help me with it, I have merged them into a new list, but the new list is in order, meaning that he brought all the first list and placed it above and then all of the second list and placed it below, is there a way to merge them but does the process Merge randomly?

Comment: @MedoAhmed Hello! Go ahead and do your_list.shuffle() just after you merge them 